# In PhotoKit, modifying PHAsset leaves original around. How? Overridable?

Tags: ios, ios8, photokit, photosframework

It seems like modifications to a particular `PHAsset` photo keep a version of the original around somehow, in order to be able to do this:

[image: revert to original]

1. Is this documented (from a programming standpoint) somewhere?
2. Can the original asset ever be overwritten?

Comment: Why on Earth you would want modify original? I just can't see the case. I'm so happy this feature exist.

Comment: I'm happy the feature exists too, but it also takes up more memory. If you wanted more memory, and were willing to ditch the originals, it would be a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PHImageManager: requestImageForAsset:` [reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:) gives some detail of what's going on here.

It seems like you can never overwrite the original image data (the asset is technically just metadata) as you can specify `PHImageRequestOptions` for an image request which include a `version` of `PHImageRequestOptionsVersionOriginal`. From the `PHImageRequestOptions` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageRequestOptions_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PHImageRequestOptions/version):

> Request the original, highest-fidelity version of the image asset.
>
> The resulting image is originally captured or imported version of the asset, regardless of any edits made.